# How to create SQL style join on two Elasticsearch indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch, join, search

I have two Elasticsearch indexes. I want to be able to search them in a similar way to an SQL join.

One index stores data for Lessons and contains a reference to the Locations index using the id of the location document.

What I'm trying to do in essence is a typical SQL join.
SELECT * FROM Lessons L JOIN Locations LC ON L.location_id = LC.id

My first solution would be to add the locations info into the Lesson index when I update a document. This would be the correct approach in the methodology of Elasticsearch - flat data. However the problem is that the two sets of data are maintained independently. So when a Location is updated all the relevant Lessons documents would need to be updated.

The second solution I've looked at are joining queries in Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html , however from what I understand from the documentation this not able between different indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use terms lookup .

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup

But if there are too many terms involved in join - performance would be a concern. Also elastic limits them to 65536 ( in newer versions i guess)